# How to create an account on Brownie

Tags: python, solidity, brownie

I am looking to create accounts on Brownie for deploying contracts but I am not sure how to do this. I have looked online how to do this and I havent found it.

I am running python 3.7 and have brownie installed and working as intended. I have also run brownie using a gnache cli. Any help would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create accounts on brownie use

```
brownie accounts new account-name
```

you can then add your private key as well as password encrypt.

You can check to see if this account was made correctly using

```
brownie accounts list
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you are trying to add accounts through the brownie ./scripts folder:

add.py

```
from brownie import accounts
def add_account():
    print(len(accounts)
    for i in range(10):
        accounts.add() #adds a random account with mnemonic & address to the network
    print(len(accounts))

def main():
    add_account()
```

You can then execute this in you shell:

> brownie run .\scripts\add.py --network [network]

For further information look here:
https://eth-brownie.readthedocs.io/en/stable/core-accounts.html

Answer (score 0):

- In a development environment, it is possible to send transactions from an address without having that address's private key.

Source: https://eth-brownie.readthedocs.io/en/stable/core-accounts.html

```py
accounts.at("0x0000000000000000000000000000000000001337", force=True)
<Account '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000001337'>
```